# Cartoony stretch sound

Tags: cartoon, foley, recording, sound-effects

Any ideas on how to get that classic rubbery stretch sound that is popular in cartoons? 
I tried a lot of different props, even tried using som screetching and creaking, but it's not working very well. Are there any specific props that are great for getting stretch sounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start off with slowly run a (damp) finger along a deflated balloon.

Then record unrolling a large roll of parcel tape.

Fiddle with the pitch of each sound, EQ them, put them together, and you should have something good, or at least good for a basis.

Comment: @David  Glad to hear it :-) 


Answer (score 0):

Tried rubber gloves?

Comment: That was my first thought, but the ones makes almost no sound at all. I'll try getting a couple of different brands and see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Empty water tank from the water cooler, the big one. 
Roll it on floor while hold a mic above it, squeeze your finger against it and rub.